# mocha hooks, only methods not working

Tags: mocha.js

The mocha hooks like `before(), after(), beforeEach(), afterEach()` are not working. Also the `only` method too not working.  None of the `beforeEach` is called. I get an error `has no method 'only'`. Below is the code.

```
describe('Array', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
      console.log('before every test')
    })
  describe.only('#indexOf()', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
      console.log('before every test')
    })
    it.only('should return -1 unless present', function(){
        assert.equal(1,2)
    })
    it('should return the index when present', function(){
        assert.equal(1,2);
    })
  })
})

beforeEach(function(){
  console.log('before every test')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. You need to add:

```
var assert = require('assert');
```

at top. And, be sure you `npm install -g mocha`.

Then, I get:

```
$ mocha -R spec temp.js


  Array
    #indexOf()
      ◦ should return -1 unless present: before every test
before every test
before every test
      1) should return -1 unless present
      ◦ should return the index when present: before every test
before every test
before every test
      2) should return the index when present


  0 passing (16ms)
  2 failing

  1) Array #indexOf() should return -1 unless present:
     AssertionError: 1 == 2
      at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/dan/Dropbox/Documents/dev/spock/temp.js:12:16)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:211:32)
      at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:355:10)
      at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:401:12
      at next (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:281:14)
      at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:290:7
      at next (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:234:23)
      at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:253:7
      at Hook.Runnable.run (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:213:5)
      at next (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:246:10)
      at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:258:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)

  2) Array #indexOf() should return the index when present:
     AssertionError: 1 == 2
      at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/dan/Dropbox/Documents/dev/spock/temp.js:15:16)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:211:32)
      at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:355:10)
      at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:401:12
      at next (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:281:14)
      at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:290:7
      at next (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:234:23)
      at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:253:7
      at Hook.Runnable.run (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:213:5)
      at next (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:246:10)
      at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:258:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Note that your `it.only` is being ignored because the `describe.only` is encountered first. If you aren't able to replicate this output, please report what version of node and npm you're using.

Comment: describe.only was overriding it for me, thanks